# Como criar barra de progresso para envio de arquivo via API do Google Drive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-drive-api

Estou enviando arquivo para o Google Drive pela API deles. O `request.Upload();` está demorando sem nenhum retorno. Como faço um progresso? Pode ser com um `for` mesmo sem interface gráfica.

Método de envio:

```
 public static File UploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile, string _parent)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
        {
            File body = new File();
            body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
            body.Description = "Teste";
            body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
            body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

            // monta os bytes
            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
            try
            {
                FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, body.MimeType);
                request.Upload();
                return request.ResponseBody;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + _uploadFile);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Qual o ambiente da aplicação? WPF? Web?

Comment: Windows forms...

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Você terá que usar o evento `ProgressChanged`:

```
 FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, body.MimeType);
 request.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged;
 ....

 private static void Upload_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
 {            
     // calcule aqui a porcentagem a partir do total de bytes do seu arquivo 
     Console.WriteLine("Bytes enviados: " + progress.BytesSent);
 }
```

Usando esse evento, basta fazer uma conta com o total de bytes do seu arquivo e a propriedade `BytesSent` do objeto recebido no parâmetro do evento. Daí fica fácil usar qualquer controle de progresso ou mesmo um texto com a porcentagem.

Porém, terá que fazer o upload de forma assíncrona. Troque a linha:

```
request.Upload();
```

Para

```
request.UploadAsync();
```

Referência: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload

Comment: não funcionou, nem entra nesse changed.

Comment: sabe o q pode ser?

Comment: Ele entrou porem so mostra quando inicia e quando termina, sabe o que pode ser? @MarcusVinicius

Comment: Quero o percentual completo.

Comment: Não sei o que pode estar ocorrendo, testei aqui e foi normal, do jeito que postei. Dá uma olhada no exemplo da documentação oficial https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload. Veja se não está faltando alguma coisa no seu código.

Comment: Qual o tamanho dos arquivos que você está usando para enviar? Dependendo do tamanho do arquivo e da velocidade da conexão, pode ser necessário alterar o valor da propriedade `ChunkSize` do request. Essa propriedade determina o tamanho de cada parte do arquivo enviado ao servidor. Para cada parte enviada, o callback `ProgressChanged` é chamado.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que li da documentação, [`InsertMediaUpload`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v2_1_1FilesResource_1_1InsertMediaUpload.html) deriva [`ResumableUpload<TRequest>`](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Upload_1_1ResumableUpload-g.html).

O percentual pode ser obtido através do método [`GetProgress`](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Upload_1_1ResumableUpload-g.html#a6a3791c8d0a6334de7eb3c71f0fd2f41). Também [como na resposta do @MarcusVinicius](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Upload_1_1ResumableUpload-g.html#a6a3791c8d0a6334de7eb3c71f0fd2f41), é possível escrever um *callback* para enviar isso para uma tela ou para algum outro lugar. No exemplo dele, é enviado para o *Console*.